# Dynamic DbContext string not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF6 (db first) and I want to set my database settings (server, catalog) in a Settings.settings file. I've created a partial class like this:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MyAppEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MyAppEntities(String connString)
            : base(BuildConnectionString("SERVERNAME", "DATABASE"))
        {
        }

        private static String BuildConnectionString(String DataSource, String Database)
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            sqlBuilder.DataSource = DataSource;
            sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = Database;
            sqlBuilder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;
            sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
            sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;

            return sqlBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my application (WinForm), it doesn't hit this partial class and uses the MyAppEntities class from the MyAppEntities.Context.cs file created by EF6:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class MyAppEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MyAppEntities()
            : base("name=MyAppEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Table2> Table2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my app (Form1.cs) I'm doing something like this:

```
using(MyAppEntities context = new MyAppEntities())
{
    var tableData = context.Table1.ToList();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have 2 constructors (the fact that they're spread among 2 partial classes is irrelevant) and by `new MyAppEntities()` you're calling the one without parameters (that was automatically generated). If you want to call the other constructor use `new MyAppEntities("SomeConnectionString")`. It's also unclear why is your constructor expecting a string parameter at all if you don't do anything with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare additional partial class for extending existing one.

```
partial class MyAppEntities
{
  public MyAppEntities(string nameOrConnectionString)
    : base(nameOrConnectionString)
  {
  }
}
```

Move your `BuildConnectionString` somewhere.. maybe some helper class.
And pass your `connectionString` before DbContext initialisation.

```
var connectionString = DbHelper.BuildConnectionString("SERVERNAME", "DATABASE");
using(MyAppEntities context = new MyAppEntities(connectionString))
{
    var tableData = context.Table1.ToList();
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I can use the helper class to get the servername and database via Settings.Default.ServerName / .Database. Then build the EntityConnection string and create a connection. In this way it does not matter what the name of the server or database is. It can be set at runtime by the user.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about how your partial class looks like when it is merged into one class, it will have two constructors... one takes a `string` and the other is parameterless:

```
    public MyAppEntities(String connString)
        : base(BuildConnectionString("SERVERNAME", "DATABASE"))
    {
    }

    public MyAppEntities()
        : base("name=MyAppEntities")
    {
    }
```

When you create the instance of the class, you call the paremeterless one, which calls the base class with `"name=MyAppEntities"`, not the constructor that takes a string and calls the `BuildConnectionString` method.

```
MyAppEntities context = new MyAppEntities()
```